# SharePoint CSOM ambiguous call to EnsureFolderPath

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint-online, csom

I am developing a VSTO Addin for Visio that needs to check whether a SharePoint Document folder exists, and if not to then create the folder. The relevant code can be seen below:

```
            using (ClientContext context = GetContext(this.Site).Result)
            {

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder folder = context.Web.EnsureFolderPath(webRelativeUrl: folderName, expressions: null);
                context.Load(folder);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                return folder.Name;
            }
```

Visual Studio 2019 is returing the following error, to the effect that the method call is ambiguous:

```
Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileFolderExtensions.EnsureFolderPath(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web, string, params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder, object>>[])' and 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileFolderExtensions.EnsureFolderPath(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web, string, params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder, object>>[])'    ModelGenSharePointClient
```

My calling class is using the following assemblies, but I can't figure out why there is an ambguity:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using ModelGenConfiguration;
using OfficeDevPnP.Core;
using OfficeDevPnP.Core.Pages;
using System;
using System.Security;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using Log = log4net;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
```

Any thoughts would be gratefully received.

Thanks and regards,
Andrew

Comment: The signature of both methods looks identical, are you referencing two versions of the same assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to have been clashing assemblies

```
<PackageReference Include="PnP.Core" Version="1.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="PnP.Framework" Version="1.5.0" />
<PackageReference Include="SharePointPnPModernizationOnline" Version="1.0.2012" />
<PackageReference Include="SharePointPnPCoreOnline" Version="3.28.2012" />
```

Removing PnP.* and SharePointPnPModernizationOnline assemblies and replacing with SharePointPnPCoreOnline appears to have resolved the issue